# Override Django LoginView Error Message With Custom AuthenticationForm

Tags: django, forms, django-authentication, loginview

I have a class-based view that subclasses `LoginView`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):

def get_success_url(self):
    url = self.get_redirect_url()
    return url or reverse_lazy('knowledgebase:user_home', kwargs={
        'username':self.request.user.username,
    })
```

I want to override the error message if a user's email is not yet active because they have to click a link sent to their email address. The current default message looks like this:

[image: override LoginView error message]

Instead of saying:

> Please enter a correct email address and password. Note that both
>   fields may be case-sensitive.

I want to say something to the effect of:

> Please confirm your email so you can log in.

I tried:

#### accounts/forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class PickyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _("Please confirm your email so you can log in."),
                code='inactive',
            )
```

#### accounts/views.py

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView): # 1. <--- note: this is a class-based view

    form_class = PickyAuthenticationForm # 2. <--- note: define form here?

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = self.get_redirect_url()
        return url or reverse_lazy('knowledgebase:user_home', kwargs={
            'username':self.request.user.username,
        })
```

The result is absolutely no effect when I try to log in with a user that **does** exist, but hasn't verified their email address yet.

[AuthenticationForm docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Method - 1

Django uses [**`ModelBackend`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend) as default [**`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#authentication-backends) and which does not authenticate the inactive users.

This is also stated in [Authorization for inactive users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#authorization-for-inactive-users) sections,

> An inactive user is one that has its `is_active` field set to `False`. The
> `ModelBackend` and `RemoteUserBackend` authentication backends prohibits
> these users from authenticating. If a custom user model doesn’t have
> an `is_active` field, all users will be allowed to authenticate.

So, set [**`AllowAllUsersModelBackend`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend) as your **`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`** in **`settings.py`**

```
# settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```

#### How much does it affect my Django app?

It doesn't affect anything other than the authentication. If we look into the [source code of **`AllowAllUsersModelBackend`** class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/659a73bc0a2df9be856e23fcfc6cc66d0d1a35fd/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L163) we can see it just allowing the ***inactive*** users to authenticate.

---

## Method - 2

Personally, I don't recommend this method since *method-1* is the Django way of tackling this issue.

Override the **`clean(...)`** method of **`PickyAuthenticationForm`** class and call the **`AllowAllUsersModelBackend`** backend as,

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import AllowAllUsersModelBackend


class PickyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username is not None and password:
            backend = AllowAllUsersModelBackend()
            self.user_cache = backend.authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Please confirm your email so you can log in.",
                code='inactive',
            )
```

**Result Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `AllowAllUsersModelBackend`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend

Here you will get instruction for setting custom backend

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced setting up a custom backend is the solution when I simply want to override a message. I did a temporary fix by defining `form_invalid`. Yes it's hacky but for now, it'll do the trick. Doubt this will help anyone but it was interesting to discover `form.errors`. Maybe someone can build off this to solve their specific problem.

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    """If the form is invalid, render the invalid form."""
    #TODO: This is EXTREMELY HACKY!
    if form.errors:
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email, username=None).exists():
            if len(form.errors['__all__']) == 1:
                form.errors['__all__'][0] = 'Please confirm your email to log in.'
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Comment: Hey, u just need to add this line `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']` at settings.py file. that's it. No extra setup here. My answer above simply try to explain that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll look into it. I appreciate your help and ideas.